# Query with parameters - AWS Amplify - Android

Tags: aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I am having trouble figuring out how to pass a parameter to a query. In this case, I want to get a user by name field. I know I can pass an id, but how do I pass another field? Do I need to create a secondary index?

```
        private AWSAppSyncClient mAWSAppSyncClient;
        mAWSAppSyncClient.query(GetUserQuery.builder().build())
                .responseFetcher(AppSyncResponseFetchers.CACHE_AND_NETWORK)
                .enqueue(userCallback);


query GetUser($id: ID!) {
  getUser(id: $id) {
    id
    userId
    name
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ListUsers (ListXXXX) to query with multiple parameters.

Example - query by name = "aaa":

```
ModelStringFilterInput modelStringFilterInput = ModelStringFilterInput.builder().eq("aaa").build();
ModelUserFilterInput modelUserFilterInput = ModelUserFilterInput.builder().name(modelStringFilterInput).build();
mAWSAppSyncClient.query(ListUsersQuery.builder().filter(modelUserFilterInput).build())
        .responseFetcher(AppSyncResponseFetchers.CACHE_AND_NETWORK)
        .enqueue(userCallback);


private GraphQLCall.Callback<ListUsersQuery.Data> userCallback = new GraphQLCall.Callback<ListUsersQuery.Data>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@Nonnull Response<ListUsersQuery.Data> response) {
        Log.d(TAG, response.data().listUsers().items().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@Nonnull ApolloException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
    }
};
```